# Sharepoint server 2013 storage

Tags: 2013, document-library, sharepoint-server, remote-blob-storage

I want to know how to setup a file storage to store documents in Sharepoint.

What kind of types are there?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you want to store documents? Why not use a document library?

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by document storage.
If you want to store documents in SharePoint then you can use the [Document Library](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/working-with-sharepoint-document-libraries-HA001141287.aspx) to store document or [assets library to store video, images etc](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/set-up-an-asset-library-to-store-image-audio-or-video-files-HA102785730.aspx).

But you are talking about the back-end storage than everything in SharePoint store into the [Content Database.](http://sharepointrelated.com/tag/content-database/) their is another method to store data into [file system using the Remote Blob Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748649%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

http://www.avepoint.com/community/team-blog/the-case-for-remote-blob-storage-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013/